# how to set the exact width in svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

If I hover over the rectangle, the border size is exceed the rectangle size. I know because parent node width is `100` that's why the rectangle border is shown.

If I set the parent node width as `40`, it's working fine but I need that same behavior without changing parent node's `width` and `stroke-width`.

How can I achieve this?

```js
// In mouse hover, I have set the style:
var links = $('#ch');
links.hover(function() {
  $('#ch').attr('class', 'st');
}, function() { //mouseout
  $('#ch').attr('class', '');
});
```

```css
.st {
  stroke-width: 60px;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg id='par' width="100" height="40">
  <rect id='ch' width="40" height="40" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. Would wrapping the outer svg element in an inner svg element width/height 40 do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer,

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipRect">
            <rect width="40" height="40" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect id ='ch' width="40" height="40" clip-path=url(#clipRect)   style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" stroke-width="8px" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3eXfk/160/)

Answer (score 1):

What's preventing the svg from overflowing is `svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}` in your UA styles (on chrome),

So if you set it to `visible` it will work:

```css
svg:not(:root) { overflow : visible; }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/3eXfk/154/)**

Comment: that's not correct.. in default svg rect behavior is, if we set the stroke with as 100 but actual rect width as 50 the size of the rect width  is will not increased and sets border inside the rect

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? Changing the fill colour would be simpler.

Other ways would be creating a clipPath or using the clip CSS property.

```js
// In mouse hover, I have set the style:
var links = $('#ch');
links.hover(function() {
  $('#ch').attr('class', 'st');
}, function() { //mouseout
  $('#ch').attr('class', '');
});
```

```css
.st {
  stroke-width: 60px;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg id='par' width="100" height="40">
  <svg width="40" height="40">
      <rect id='ch' width="40" height="40" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```